# google maps IE7 marker setIcon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-7, marker

I have a problem with ie7 and method setIcon of marker google maps.

when used for a single item `marker.setIcon(image)` works OK, but when I use an array `marker [i].setIcon(image)` does not work, the error of IE is the object has that method.

Anyone know the cause?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a larger snippet of code that reproduces this?  I'd be interested to see how the markers get into the array.

Comment: Also, please show the exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is solved, i don't know because but ie add element with name "IndexOf" in the array...

The solution:

```
       for(var ii in markers) //Cambio de color - todos a negro
        { 
            if(ii == 'indexOf')
                continue;
             markers[ii].setIcon(image);
        }
```

bamnet- For introduce markers in array:

[Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Thanks.